# Evitar que el body se ejecute si no está el Footer (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

En mi HTML tengo un `<footer></footer>` vacío, pues los elementos los agrego mediante javascript de esta forma:

```
let title = document.title;
document.querySelector("footer").innerHTML =

`<p class="linea"><strong> ${title} </strong></p>
<p class="linea"><i class="fa-solid fa-code"></i> PROYECTO DE CÓDIGO ABIERTO EN <a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank">GITHUB</a></p>
<p class="linea"> Desarrollador: <a href="#">Dev</a></p>`
```

Y mi body carga el resto de funciones así:

```
<body onload="toWrite();">
```

Me gustaría saber si es posible hacer que el body no cargue o no se ejecuten las funciones **si no está la etiqueta footer.** Es decir, que si alguien borra el footer no pueda usar el resto de funciones.

El código será gratuito y quisiera que quienes lo descarguen no borren los créditos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```js
if (document.body.contains(document.querySelector("footer"))) {
  let title = document.title;
  document.querySelector("footer").innerHTML =
    `<p class="linea"><strong> ${title} </strong></p>
<p class="linea"><i class="fa-solid fa-code"></i> PROYECTO DE CÓDIGO ABIERTO EN <a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank">GITHUB</a></p>
<p class="linea"> Desarrollador: <a href="#">Dev</a></p>`

} else {
  document.body.innerHTML = "Por favor, no elimine los créditos"
}
```

```html
<body onload="toWrite();">
  <nofooter></nofooter>
```

donde lo que hacemos es montar un condicional donde comprobamos si elemento **footer** existe en el **body** gracias al método [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/contains):

```
    if (document.body.contains(document.querySelector("footer"))) {
```

y en caso de que no exista sobreescribimos todo el **body** con cualquier cosa, por ejemplo:

```
} else {
      document.body.innerHTML = "Por favor, no elimine los créditos"
    }
```

Comment: Graciaas! Justo lo que necesitaba

Comment: disculpe cree que podría ayudarme con mi última prregunta o si tiene algún medio por donde pueda contactarlo para ver si me ayuda a resolverla?:(